# Order from multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

So here is my code basically what it selects is a support ticket I am trying to make it so that it selects all the tickets from the user however when someone replies to the ticket I need that one to be at the top just wondering why the two orders that I have on this select don't work how intended. Thankyou.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `usr_tickets` 
                         WHERE `username` = '$username' 
                         ORDER BY `id` DESC, `replied` DESC")or die(mysql_error());
```

So the problem is more here on the line

```
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `replied` DESC")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Swap them maybe? ORDER BY `replied` DESC, `id` DESC

Comment: @AbraCadaver haha how come it was that simple aha xD thankyou works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` will be created in order when the ticket is created (and they will be unique) and you sort on that first.  You need to sort on `replied` first which I assume is a date or time:

```
ORDER BY `replied` DESC, `id` DESC
```

Comment: Great fast response thankyou, Will mark this as the answer shortly.